# MPAndroid Chart by Date

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a date object with includes a level (y-axis), a type (colour) and a date (x-axis).

I understand that I can make a [grouped barchart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#grouped-barchart) using MPAndroidChart but how do I change the x values to show the date?

[image: chart]

Comment: Your link, a few lines up the page, there is a `IAxisValueFormatter ` sample. This should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IAxisValueFormatter like so:

```
public class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private SimpleDateFormat mFormat;

    public MyAxisValueFormatter() {

        // format values to 1 decimal digit
        mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
        return mFormat.format(value);
    }

    /** this is only needed if numbers are returned, else return 0 */
    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() { return 0; }
}
```